# What is "My" in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

What is "My" in VB.NET ? It is a namespace but what does it hold?

Comment: -1 for "first google hit" type of question...

Answer (score 5):

Here's an overview of all the namespaces contained in the My Namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5btzf5yk.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[It's a collection of useful methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5btzf5yk.aspx).